# Dump function doesn't show character-set

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I'm trying to check in which characterset **`DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()`** is returning the result. I tried to check it like that.

```
SELECT DUMP(
            CAST(
                  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('FUNCTION',  'MyFUNCTION', 'SCHEME')  
                  AS VARCHAR2(4000)
                ), 
            16
           )  
  FROM dual
```

However it doesn't show me characterset. I'm only getting result like this:

```
Typ=1 Len=1739: a,2...
```

My `NLS_CHARACTERSET` returns `WE8MSWIN1252`. Does **`GET_DDL()`** returns also in this characterset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the second dump argument from 16 to 1016:

```
SELECT dump (CAST(DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('FUNCTION',  'MyFUNCTION', 'SCHEME')  AS VARCHAR2(4000)), 16)  FROM DUAL
```

```
Typ=1 Len=126 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: a ...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=609766ebd9a50df1b52b50fa0efd7968)

This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DUMP.html#GUID-A05793C9-B35D-4BA7-B68C-E3693BCF47A5):

> By default, the return value contains no character set information. To retrieve the character set name of *expr*, add 1000 to any of the preceding format values.

---

You also asked:

> My `NLS_CHARACTERSET` returns `WE8MSWIN1252`. Does GET_DDL returns also in this characterset?

You are casting the result of the GET_DDL call to varchar2, so dump will tell you the character set of that cast value, which will be in your NLS_CHARACTERSET. The value actually returned by GET_DDL is a CLOB, which will also be in your NLS_CHARACTERSET.